# AssertionError when calling DropBox getAccountInfo()

Tags: java, dropbox, assertion

I'm experiencing a strange but with DropBox that I wasn't experiencing last week.  I have created a simple java console app to pull files down from DropBox and store then locally and this was working but for some reason it's failing now.  The AccessToken and UserID are being read in from a file.

```
MyDBAccessToken = params.get(0);
MyDBUserID      = params.get(1);
MyDBUrlState    = null;

DbxAuthFinish authToken  = new DbxAuthFinish(MyDBAccessToken, MyDBUserID, MyDBUrlState);
DbxRequestConfig config  = new DbxRequestConfig( "JavaTutorial/1.0", Locale.getDefault().toString());
DbxClient MyDBClient     = new DbxClient(config, authToken.accessToken);
System.out.println("Linked to DropBox account: " + MyDBClient.getAccountInfo().displayName + " ID " + MyDBClient.getAccountInfo().userId);
```

Here is my stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: bad index: -1, field = "datastores"
at com.dropbox.core.DbxAccountInfo$Quota$1.read(DbxAccountInfo.java:91)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxAccountInfo$Quota$1.read(DbxAccountInfo.java:66)
at com.dropbox.core.json.JsonReader.readField(JsonReader.java:26)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxAccountInfo$1.read(DbxAccountInfo.java:152)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxAccountInfo$1.read(DbxAccountInfo.java:128)
at com.dropbox.core.json.JsonReader.readFully(JsonReader.java:349)
at com.dropbox.core.json.JsonReader.readFully(JsonReader.java:238)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.readJsonFromResponse(DbxRequestUtil.java:218)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient$4.handle(DbxClient.java:275)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient$4.handle(DbxClient.java:270)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.doGet(DbxRequestUtil.java:269)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.doGet(DbxClient.java:1804)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.getAccountInfo(DbxClient.java:270)
```

Comment: What version of dropbox-core you're using?

Comment: I've used both 1.7.2 and 1.7.3

Answer (score 2):

It seems like whatever JSON the library was trying to parse was corrupted.

That being said, an `AssertionError` being propagated out of a public API in a production setting is always a bug. An assertion error basically means an assumption the library author made is not always true. The code either needs to be corrected so that the assumption is always true, or a more relevant `Exception` subclass should be thrown and documented as part of the API.

In fact, here is the issue on the Dropbox issue tracker for that library.

[DbxClient.getAccountInfo fails with AssertionError.](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/issues/5)

You may wish to comment on that issue and provide more details (i.e a stacktrace and a description of what you were doing), as the issue submitter provided none.

Comment: Fantastic thanks!  I have added my information to that report